# How to print the elements of a circular buffer(implemented using arrays) using recursion?

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

How to print the elements of a circular queue recursively. Can someone help me fix this code snippet?

```
public void print(int rear){
  // f is the front of queue
    if(rear == f)
        return;
    else
    {
        print(rear - 1);
        System.out.println(Queue[rear - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly check my solution and I would appreciate if you upvote it if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In circular buffer, you `remove elements from the front` and `add elements at the rear`.

I don't see the need to specify `rear` as a parameter to your `print()` method.

Instead, you can implement the following code

```
public void print() {
    //f -> front and r -> rear
    if (f == r) {
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(Q[f]);
    f = (f + 1) % N;
    print();
}
```

You need not dequeue all the elements from the queue if you wish and just print them as above.
If you wish to avoid recursion, simple make it loop within `print()` block.

```
public void print() {
    while (f != r) {
        System.out.println(Q[f]);
        f = (f + 1) % N;
        // print(); // no more calling recursion
    }
}
```

---

Note: For your reference, my implementation for enqueue and dequeue is as follows

```
public void enqueue(Object obj) throws QueueFullException {
    if (isFull()) {
        // some exception
    } else {
        Q[r] = obj;
        r = (r + 1) % N;
    }
}

public Object dequeue() throws QueueEmptyException {
    Object item;
    if (isEmpty()) {
        // some exception
    } else {
        item = Q[f];
        Q[f] = null;
        f = (f + 1) % N;
    }
    return item;
}
```